# Matlab: moving sum with different parameters (lookback periods)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

i asked the same problem on matlab central, but have not received an answer yet.http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/343438

i like to calculate a momentum indicator for a time series of index prices.
However the look back period should be different for each index.

e.g.

A is a matrix a time series of norm. distributed returns
B is the total return time series
LBP is the lookback period for each index
S is the signal, where S(i,j) is 1, when the return over the look back period is positve, -1 when negative and 0 when equal

```
A = normrnd(0.05/260,0.15/sqrt(260),10,2);
B = cumprod(A+1);
LBP = [2 4];
S = NaN(size(B));

S(1+LBP(1):end,1)= sign(B(1+LBP(1):end,1)-B(1:end-LBP(1),1));
S(1+LBP(2):end,2)= sign(B(1+LBP(2):end,2)-B(1:end-LBP(2),2));
```

alternatively one can calculate a moving sum (of returns, in that case matrix A)

Is there a more elegant way to calculate the signal (indicator), so that i can avoid an iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemed like another good setup for [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) play -

```
%// Store number of rows in B 
N = size(B,1);

%// Create masks for "1+LBP(x):end" & "1:end-LBP(x)" for all iterations
mask1 = bsxfun(@gt,(1:N)',LBP);     %'//
mask2 = bsxfun(@le,(1:N)',N-LBP);   %'// OR flipud(mask1)

%// Setup output array & insert sign values computed from masked B
S_out = NaN(size(B));
S_out(mask1) = sign(B(mask1) - B(mask2));
```

Comment: As a note: if you do `bsxfun(@gt,(1:N)',LBP);    %'//` thus move your apostrophe, you can still add comments in SO markdown

Comment: @Adriaan If I am not adding any comments, so it's basically the same, right?

Comment: Yes. Both will work when copying to MATLAB. It was more of a general prettiness remark, `bsxfun(@gt,(1:N)',LBP); %'//text` looks prettier than the other way around doesn't it?

Comment: @Adriaan Look! I had to put a comment there and I used your suggestion, so thanks! :)